# Error trying to read oracle database with python

Tags: python, python-3.x, oracle, cx-oracle

So I am running this example that I found on Oracle's site on my linux machine. I have seen questions like this before, but the suggestions were not relevant in my case. I used pip install to download cx_oracle and I'm not entirely sure why it is failing to connect.

```
import cx_Oracle

con = cx_Oracle.connect('pythonhol/welcome@127.0.0.1/orcl')
print (con.version)

con.close()
```

Here is the error that I get:

*cx_Oracle.DatabaseError: DPI-1047: 64-bit Oracle Client library cannot be loaded: "libclntsh.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory". See https://oracle.github.io/odpi/doc/installation.html#linux for help*

I've looked up this error, but it seems as if this is unrelated to Oracle based on my google searches. Any guidance is appreciated.

Comment: Did you follow the instructions at that link for installing the 64-bit Oracle client library? cx_oracle won't work without it.

Comment: Yes that library has been installed

Comment: Ok. Is the location where you unzipped it in your LD_LIBRARY_PATH? `echo $LD_LIBRARY_PATH` See also the official troubleshooting doc: http://cx-oracle.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installation.html#troubleshooting

Comment: So where is `libclntsh.so` on your machine?

Comment: $LD_LIBRARY_PATH is located here: /home/david/Documents/oracle:       as is the pyhton file i am running

Comment: @BobJarvis that particular file is in the installed oracle client which is located in the LD_LIBRARY_PATH above

Comment: What Oracle Client library do you have installed? How did you install it? What is the contents of your LD_LIBRARY_PATH environment variable? And what are the contents of the directory that is mentioned in LD_LIBRARY_PATH? You either don't have the Oracle Client installed at all....or you have it installed incorrectly. If you provided that information it will help us help you.

Answer (score 0):

Seems you don't install the oracle client library in your system.
Before connecting to the oracle database server you have to install client package for oracle database server, You can download instant client library from [oracle client library.](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/database-technologies/instant-client/downloads/index.html)

After installation run snippet:

```
       import cx_Oracle

       con = cx_Oracle.connect('pythonhol/welcome@127.0.0.1/orcl')
       print ('version:', con.version)

       con.close()
       # output: version: 12.0.1
```

Comment: Unfortunately I do already have the appropriate client library installed. Thanks for the suggestion